# How to display <tag> </tag> as opposed to <tag/> in XStream

Tags: xml, xstream

When I serialize my objects into xml, empty tags are set as `<tag\>`

I would like `<tag></tag>`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `<tag></tag>` and `<tag />` mean exactly the same thing in XML, most XML parser choose to use the representation that takes less space.

As far as I know, this is not something a user can control.